# How to set icon of .exe generated with dart compile

Tags: dart, exe

I'm generating a `.exe` for my dart console application with

```bash
dart compile exe .\bin\main.dart
```

How can I set an icon for this generated `.exe` so that it's not blank?

I've googled it and only found flutter-related answers

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible.